# multiple file upload laravel controller not working

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm trying to multiple file upload foreach not working

```
 if($request->hasfile('document')){
                
                $doc_name=[];
                $doc_url=[];
                $file=$request->file('document');
      
                foreach($file as $doc){
                   
                    $fileName ="emp". $emp_id."-".time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $doc_name[] = $fileName;
                    $request->document->move(public_path("/storage/expense"),$fileName);
                    $filePath='/storage/expense/'.$fileName;
                    $doc_url=$filePath;
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs(public_path("/storage/expense"),$file, basename($files->getClientOriginalName())); 
Try This Please..

Comment: it's not come inside of foreach loop

Comment: `$doc->move(...)` instead of `$request->document->move(...)`